# Hurewicz fibration among categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

All Hurewicz fibrations in the category $Top$ of topological spaces are fibrations in all subcategories of $Top$,  such as the category $CG$ of compactly generated spaces, but not conversely.

My request is: an example of a Hurewicz fibration in $CG$ that is not a Hurewicz fibration in $Top$.